# Верно ли решение задачи?

Tags: математика, графы, логика

В классе 62 ученика. У каждого ученика есть 3 друга ( дружба всегда взаимна). При этом все ученики упорядочены по рейтингу. Будем считать, что ученик учится лучше своих друзей, если у него есть хотя бы 2 друга, которые учатся хуже. Какое максимальное количество учеников, которые учатся лучше своих друзей?
Решение: Пронумеруем учеников от 1 до 62, первый дружит с 2 3 и 4. Дальше если 2 3 и 4 дружат между собой, то они уже не могут считаться лучшими, соответственно 2 дружит с 5 и 6, 3 с 7 и 8, 4 с 9 и 10. И т.д.
Получается 1 дружит с 3 учениками, эти 3 с 6 учениками и т д ( 1 -> 3 -> 6 -> 12 -> 24) Итого 46 учеников. Плюс у последних 24 учеников еще не хватает по 2 друга.  У нас осталось 16 учеников, каждый из них берет по 3 друга из 24, и они уже не являются учениками которые учатся лучше других. Итого ответ 46. Верно? Или может быть другой расклад и ответ может быть больше?

Comment: У меня по той же схеме получается не 46+24 (кстати, это как?), а 30+32. Из 32 выкидывается каждый третий и получается 40.

Comment: Ну там 46+16, 24 это последние "лучшие" ученики

Comment: Ну и зачем удалил?